# Difficulties parsing json data in vb.net using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, parsing

I have serialized a json stream using Newtonsoft.Json.
Here is what the data looks like:

```
{
  "id": "55115654340-8d43-440c-8683-c3aa299e39cd",
  "timestamp": "2018-02-09T13:57:34.143Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "HELP",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "63b7b4a5-3f7f-41b1-81ec-fcc6f70fb173",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 5000,
      "intentName": "HELP"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout.",
    "webhookTimedOut": true
  },
  "sessionId": "f761206e-76d4-4a08-b95d-57a39694cb00"
}


 using
   Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of 
   String, Object))(decodedString)
```

I can get the id value by: `var_id = jsonResulttodict.Item("id")`

how do I get the values that are deeper, like the value of resolvedQuery that is below result ?

and also the value of intentName under metadata which is under result....

Thank you

Comment: That is not a good title for a question. Also: add the tag of the programming language you are using.

Comment: `jsonResulttodict.Item("result").item("resolvedQuery")` ?

Comment: Thank you Patrick!